# AppleScript events not triggering for received SMS?

Tags: applescript

For hours, I'm trying to write script, which will automatically copy text from received SMS (iPhone > paired Mac) into the clipboard. Messages sent via iMessages protocol works well, events are always triggered (on message received, on active chat message received, on message sent etc.). But in case of SMS (not **iMessage), the events **on message received** / on** active chat message received are triggered only sometimes. I even didn't found out when.

The code is simple, something like this:

```
using terms from application "Messages"  

on message received theMessage from theBuddy for theChat with eventDescription  
  say "received"  
  display notification "received"  
end message received  

on active chat message received with eventDescription  
  say "received active"  
  display notification "received active"  
end active chat message received  

on message sent theMessage for theChat  
  say "sent"  
  display notification "sent"  
end message sent  

# The following are unused but need to be defined to avoid an error  

on chat room message received  
  # do nothing  
end chat room message received  

on addressed message received  
  # do nothing  
end addressed message received  

on received text invitation  
  # do nothing  
end received text invitation  

...
```

Any clues?
Thanx a lot!